# laravel simple query builder (join & where case)

Tags: sql, laravel, join, where-clause

i have 2 table `(product & type)`

```
produk table
 -id
 -kode_produk
 -nama_produk
 -id_jenis_produk
```

and

```
jenis table
- id
- jenis_item
```

i wanna access database jenis_item from `jenis table`with query builder
so far i already try

```
$selectProduk = DB::table('produk')->where('id', $id)->join('jenis', 'produk.id_jenis_produk', '=', 'jenis.id')->first();
```

and something like this

```
$selectProduk = DB::table('produk')
                 ->join('jenis', function($join) {
                     $join->on('produk.id_jenis_item', '=', 'jenis.id')
                        ->where('produk.id', $id); // line 86 (error)
                    })->first();
```

but still failed with message error from laravel logs

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\itklan\app\controllers\ProdukController.php:86
```

where i'm missing?

---

**@Thomas Kim**

i get another error

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Missing argument 3 for Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::where(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\itklan\app\controllers\ProdukController.php on line 86 and defined' in C:\xampp\htdocs\itklan\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause.php:87
```

line 87 :

```
$selectProduk = DB::table('produk')
                        ->join('jenis', function($join) use($id) {
                            $join->on('produk.id_jenis_item', '=', 'jenis.id')
                                ->where('produk.id', $id);
                        })->first(); //line 87
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how PHP closures work. In order to use `$id`, the closure must inherit the variable from the parent scope by using the `use` keyword. For example:

```
$selectProduk = DB::table('produk')
                ->join('jenis', function($join) use($id) { // Check this line
                    $join->on('produk.id_jenis_item', '=', 'jenis.id')
                        ->where('produk.id', '=', $id);
                })->first();
```

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the use language construct.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Edit:

Also, looks like with Laravel's `JoinClause`, you need to be specific about your operators. Normally, you can do this:

```
->where('produk.id', $id);
```

And Laravel adds an equal operator for you. However, for join clauses, this will not work. You need to specify the operator.

```
->where('produk.id', '=', $id);
```

Comment: that solve one error...but i get another error...i already update in my post...please check

Comment: I edited my answer. For a JoinClause, you need to specify the operator. :)